# Why is Java's Double Metaphone only giving four letter codes?

Tags: java, codec, phonetics, metaphone

I want to use DoubleMetaphone to get a phonetic encoding of a given string. For example:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.language.DoubleMetaphone;
String s1 = "computer";
(new DoubleMetaphone()).doubleMetaphone(s1);
```

**Result**: Computer -> KMPT

The issue arises when I try to encode longer strings.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.language.DoubleMetaphone;
String s1 = "dustinhoffmanisanactor";
(new DoubleMetaphone()).doubleMetaphone(s1);
```

**Result**: dustinhoffmanisanactor -> TSTN

Clearly it's taking the first 4 encoded characters and halting. In this case Dustin -> TSTN.

I used the Python implementation of Double Metaphone and it works as expected.

```
>>>from metaphone import doublemetaphone
>>>doublemetaphone("dustinhoffmanisanactor")[0]
"TSTNFMNSNKTR"
```

Comment: Which version of `org.apache.commons.codec.language.DoubleMetaphone` are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.9. Think the issue is solved now :)

Comment: The default size is 4, see https://github.com/apache/commons-codec/blob/fe8b24cb8b9aca990adb7a9623c7db35f0bff75c/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/codec/language/DoubleMetaphone.java#L59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I needed to set the max code length.

```
String s1 = "dustinhoffmanisanactor";
DoubleMetaphone dm = new DoubleMetaphone();
dm.setMaxCodeLen(100);
dm.doubleMetaphone(s1);
```

Which gives the expected `TSTNFMNSNKTR`.